# i am getting a error when i type mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, server

i get this error when i do :  `sudo mysql_secure_installation , mysql or even try to run mysql`

Error:  `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

i have searched this in the internet and till i

i have already tried reinstalling mysql and restarting my pc. but still i am getting this error

i actually want to use wordpad in apache server and i am following this guide  `https://linuxconfig.org/wordpress-installation-ubuntu-linux-apache-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

linux shell:
ln -s your mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock